# set ActiveX checkbox properties with VBA word 2010

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, word-2010

I have searched high and low for this, but no luck.

To create a checkbox:

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1"
```

However, there are several properties associated with a checkbox, and I wanted to find out how to set them as well when I am creating the checkbox.

For example, I tried this:

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Caption:=""
```

But the code throws a "Named Argument Not Found" error while highlighting Caption:=""

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue

```
'to place it in the table, assuming only 1 table, and in this example the checkbox is placed in the second Row, first Column
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Select

Set myOB = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
With myOB.OLEFormat
.Activate
Set myObj = .Object
End With
With myObj
'now you can name the field anything you want
 .Name = "CB1"
 .Value = False
 'delete the caption, or have it say what you want
 .Caption = ""
 .Height = 22
 .Width = 22
End With
```